# Verifying the Green's Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have $i y''' + \lambda y = 0$, $0 < t < 1$, and $y(0) = y'(0) = y''(1) = 0$. I want to compute the green's function when $\lambda = 0$.

Two independent solutions of $i y''' = 0$ are $y = Ax^2$ and $y = Bx+C$ correct? So then $G(t,z) = \frac{y_{1}(z)y_{2}(t) - y_2(z)y_1(t)}{W(Z)}$ is $$G(t,z) = \frac{Az^2 \cdot (Bt+C) - (Bz+C)At^2}{At^2 \cdot B - (Bt+C)2At}$$

What I am most confused about is if my indepedent solutions are correct since i'm not sure how that the $i$ plays into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construction only applies to second order Sturm-Liouville problems.

Here you can solve the defining equation for the Greens function directly. $y'''(t)=-i\delta(t-s)$ has the general solution
$$
G(s,t)=-i\frac12(t-s)_+^2+A+Bt+Ct^2
$$
and the boundary conditions result in
$$
0=G(s,0)=A,\; 0=G_t(s,0)=B,\;0=G_{tt}(s,1)=-i+2C
$$
and consequently
$$
G(s,t)=\frac{i}2(t^2-(t-s)_+^2)
=
\frac{i}2\begin{cases}
t^2&t<s\\
s(2t-s)&t\ge s
\end{cases}
$$
where $(t-s)_+=\max(0,t-s)$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write an answer for my question. I am afraid I do not quite understand what your wrote though. Why was what I wrote incorrect? Where did $y'''(t) = -i \delta (t-s)$ come from?

Comment: It is the fundamental definition of the Green function. For a linear differential operator $L$ and the problem $L(y)=0$ the Green function $G$ is defined as the solution to $L(G_s)=δ_s$ where $G_s(t)=G(s,t)$ and $δ_s(t)=δ(t−s)$. Then $L(y)=f$ can be solved by $y(t)=\int f(s)G(s,t)\,ds$.

Comment: Okay. I suppose the textbook I am reading from uses a much simpler definition of the Green function. What does the $\delta$ mean in $\delta_s (t) = \delta(t-s)$ ?

Comment: The Dirac delta distribution. Which is twice the derivative of $x_+=\max(0,x)$ or the simple derivative of the Heaviside ramp function (all in the generalized distributional sense).

Comment: LutzL, thank you. I have a follow up question regarding this problem, but I made it a post of its own found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2034916/393978 Thanks again!