# Checking if a differential operator is self-adjoint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wish to check if the differential operator $i \frac{d^3}{dt^3}$ is self adjoint from my DE $i y''' + \lambda y = 0$, $0  <t< 1$, and $y(0) = y'(0) = y''(1) = 0$.

So I must check if $<Lv,u> = <u,Lv>$ where $<.,.>$ is the Hilbert inner product.

So

$<u,Lv> = \int_a^b u^*(t) i \frac{d^3 v}{dt^3}(t) dt = i [u^*(t) \frac{d^2v}{dt^2}(t)]_a^b - \int_a^b i \frac{d^2v}{dt^2}(t) \cdot \frac{du^*}{dt} dt  $

After this I am getting lost in the algebra or i'm just not sure what to do. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: a and b are 0 and 1 respectively. Integration by parts will integrate the derivatives of v and swap them with derivatives of u. Put in the limits as you go and things will work out.

Answer (score 2):

What you proved is, essentially, that $i\frac{d}{dx}$ is self-adjoint on the space of functions whose values vanish at the interval boundaries $x=0,1$.

As powers of self-adjoint operators are again self-adjoint, you also get that $L=-\left(i\frac{d}{dx}\right)^3$ is self-adjoint on the space of functions that have also vanishing first and second derivatives at the interval boundaries $x=0,1$.

Answer (score 2):

You must first build the eigenstate space and then check these are orthogonal. The spectral theorem is valid only for self-adjoint operators, not for arbitrary symmetric operators, so, you must check eigenstates are orthogonal! Let us say $(u,v)\not=0$ and $a\not = b$ where $a,b\in \mathrm R$. If $Lu=au$ and $Lv=bv$, then $$(Lv,u)-(v,Lu)=(a-b)(v,u)\not=0.$$

A non trivial example of this is the diagonalization of the symmetric operator $A=e^{-x}i\frac{d\ }{dx}e^{-x}$ with $x\in\mathrm{R}$. Trying to diagonalize A leads to a set of eigenfunctions that are not orthogonal. $A$ is not self-adjoint. Yet, it can also be checked that $A^2$ is self-adjoint.